# Syntax for Wget to execute same call 10 times

Tags: wget

Is there a way to call the same url 10 times in sequence via wget rather than sending the same call again manually? Thanks!!
for example, instead of sending this call manually can i have the call execute 10 times?
time wget -O test.txt --no-check-certificate https:google.com

I am basically trying to get the average response time for a url using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1 :

> Create a text file "input.txt" with the same URL copied 10 times, 1 per line.
>
> Then, add "-i input.txt" to your wget command instead of "https:google.com" (which >is incorrect anyway).
>
> This will make wget call the same URL 10 times.

Solution 2 :

> Assuming your shell is bash, you can call wget in a loop like so -
>
> for x in {1..10}; do time wget -O test.txt --no-check-certificate https://google.com ; done ;
>
> This will also call wget 10 times for the same URL.

What is the difference between the two approaches ?

> Solution1 will call the URL 10 times from a single wget instance and Solution2 will spawn a new wget instance for each of the 10 attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks i basically did the same thing to fix the problem by overwriting the file with the new response - i tried calling the url via the file did not work for me